# PostgreSQL query for this case?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have this below case statement in postgreSQL.

```
select eng.id, 
case et.id 
      when 2 then cwd.rate::text  
      when 1 then cwd.amount::text else 'SCD' end terms
```

I need to put some text like 'WC' before cwd.rate. Its giving me syntax error. Any idea how do I do this.

Comment: ....you're going to need to show what you're doing, but you're probably thinking of a `CONCAT` method?

Comment: update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: We'll assume that `cw.rate::text` and `cwd.amount::text` are text data types.  so it should be `when 2 then 'WC' || cw.rate::text else...`  if not what are your trying and what is the specific error?

Comment: What is the error message? (if a question involves an error message always include it: *in full* )